# Getting "Failed to start Selenium listener." error message while running testcafe script through saucelabs

Tags: selenium, testing, automation, testcafe, saucelabs

I am trying to run testcafe script through saucelabs. But getting the following error message.

```
MAIN failed to create listener on port 4445
MAIN possible socket error: libevent connection error
Failed to start Selenium listener. Please make sure there are no other applications using the Selenium port, or specify an alternative port for Sauce Connect via the --se-port option (exit code 2).
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like another application already used the 4445 port (see a similar discussion [here](https://github.com/theintern/intern/issues/285)).
 
Also, you can use the official Saucelabs [Troubleshooting Guide](https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Troubleshooting+Sauce+Connect) to fix this problem.